# How do I join or concat 2 dataframes where I get a new column for each row where the left_on/right_on key is the same?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Given 2 dataframes:
DF1

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Jim |
| 456 | Bob |

DF2

| record_id | model_year | make_desc | model_desc | vin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2008 | Chevy | Tahoe | cvin |
| 456 | 2020 | Hyundai | Elantra | hvin |
| 456 | 2018 | Ford | F-150 | fvin |

I want to merge/join/groupby, not sure really such that the result is:

| ID | Name | model_year1 | make_desc1 | model_desc1 | vin1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Jim | 2008 | Chevy | Tahoe | cvin |
| 456 | Bob | 2020 | Hyundai | Elantra | hvin |

| model_year2 | make_desc2 | model_desc2 | vin2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2008 | Chevy | Tahoe | cvin |
| 2018 | Ford | F150 | fvin |

(the second table of results is just more columns from the first table, i couldnt figure out the markup)

so kind of like a join, I need to be able to join data on a value
but I want to add columns instead of adding rows, when there are multiple matches,
and the number of matches cant be known upfront so it could need to add 10 columns.

I tried a horizontal concat but it doesnt seem to match on value
I have also read up a bunch on groupby, but I can't get it.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Didnt fight a straigtfoward way. Please try as explained and coded below;

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', on='ID')#Merge the two dfs
df3=df3.groupby(['ID','Name'])['JobCode'].unique().reset_index()# JobCode to list
df3[['JobCode','JobCode_x']]=pd.DataFrame(df3['JobCode'].tolist(), index= df3.index)#Create required columns




ID    Name JobCode JobCode_x
0  123  Jim     H1B      None
1  456  Bob     H1B       H2B
```

Comment: it's close but

 df3[['JobCode','JobCode_x']]=pd.DataFrame(df3['JobCode'].tolist(), index= df3.index)
requires that the column number be the same as the key(list in this case)

Comment: No, not at all. From the sample, you notice it was possible. Is the sample provided different from actual situation?

Comment: yeah, let me edit my question to be more appropriate to what I am trying to do. some of the data is legally encumbered so I'll change it.

Comment: `newdf = pd.merge(cdf,cldf, how='left', left_on='id', right_on='Dealer_ID')#Merge the two dfs

newdf=newdf.groupby(['record_id','model_year'])['vin'].unique().reset_index()# JobCode to list

newdf[['vin', 'vin_x']]=pd.DataFrame(newdf['vin'].tolist(), index= newdf.index)#Create required columns`

ValueError: Columns must be same length as key

Comment: understand, if I have 5 unique vins under one id, I could need vin1, vin2, vin3, vin4, vin5 columns created, and on the next one, no matches , then the next one 3.

Comment: i'm maybe over thinking this. I can just drop down in to python and solve it, was just trying to see if there was some kind of transpose or transform or groupby that solved it in a vectorized way.

Comment: I am thinking so. All you want to know is who owns what. This gives you an idea;`df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', left_on='ID',right_on='record_id')` If you need one individual per row this tells it all `df3.groupby(['ID','Name']).agg(list).reset_index()` Datawise, you are better having multiple rows of an entity than columns. Because columns are considered more of a database if you know what I mean. Multiple columns take more space

Comment: 100% agree, this is for a presentation to a client, and they requested this format. it's janky to be sure.

Comment: So have I answered your question and you mind giving at least an upvote